# Java - NullPointerException Issue

Tags: java

I have been working on a program and when I run it I get an error that says line 43 and 84 have a NullPointerException. This is the code. I have put comments where line 43 and 84 are. I am trying to make a word processor like Microsoft Word.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Graphics {
    // listing all the components 
    JFrame f1;
    JPanel colorspanel;
    JPanel sizepanel;
    JPanel fontpanel;
    JPanel mainpanel;
    JTextField Maintextfield;
    JLabel colorlabel;
    JLabel sizelabel;
    JLabel fontlabel;
    JButton colorbuttons[];
    JButton sizebuttons[];
    JButton fontbuttons[];

    Graphics() {
        // making instances of panels
        colorspanel = new JPanel();
        sizepanel = new JPanel();
        fontpanel = new JPanel();
        mainpanel = new JPanel();
        // setting the size of the panels
        colorspanel.setSize(216, 144);
        sizepanel.setSize(216, 144);
        fontpanel.setSize(216, 144);
        mainpanel.setSize(612, 756);    
        // making instances of button
        colorbuttons = new JButton[9];
        sizebuttons = new JButton[14];
        fontbuttons = new JButton[9];
        // setting content for buttons
        // colorbuttons
        colorbuttons[0].setBackground(Color.black);//line 43
        colorbuttons[1].setBackground(Color.red);
        colorbuttons[2].setBackground(Color.blue);
        colorbuttons[3].setBackground(Color.yellow);
        colorbuttons[4].setBackground(Color.green);
        colorbuttons[5].setBackground(Color.gray);
        colorbuttons[6].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        colorbuttons[7].setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        colorbuttons[8].setBackground(Color.pink);
        colorbuttons[9].setBackground(Color.magenta);
        // sizebuttons
        sizebuttons[0].setText("8");
        sizebuttons[1].setText("10");
        sizebuttons[2].setText("12");
        sizebuttons[3].setText("14");
        sizebuttons[4].setText("16");
        sizebuttons[5].setText("18");
        sizebuttons[6].setText("20");
        sizebuttons[7].setText("22");
        sizebuttons[8].setText("24");
        sizebuttons[9].setText("26");
        sizebuttons[10].setText("28");
        sizebuttons[11].setText("30");
        sizebuttons[12].setText("32");
        sizebuttons[13].setText("34");
        sizebuttons[14].setText("36");
        // fontbuttons
        fontbuttons[0].setText("New Times Roman");
        fontbuttons[1].setText("Blackadder ITC");
        fontbuttons[2].setText("Andy");
        fontbuttons[3].setText("Buxton Sketch");
        fontbuttons[4].setText("Arial Black");
        fontbuttons[5].setText("Comic Sans MS");
        fontbuttons[6].setText("Old English Text MT");
        fontbuttons[7].setText("SketchFlow Print");
        fontbuttons[8].setText("Harlow Solid Italic");
        fontbuttons[9].setText("Algerian");
        f1.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Graphics graphics = new Graphics();//line 84

    }

}
```

Comment: You should also be getting `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: yes i fixed the ArrayOutofBoundsException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created an array, but you never populated it with anything.  You need to put buttons in the array.  A `NullPointerException` means that you tried to reference something, but a `null` value was found, not an object with a method or property.  For example

```
Object x = null;
x.toString();  // NPE
```

vs

```
Object x = new Object();
x.toString(); // we're in business
```

In your case, you created an array (over 2 lines; just create everything on one line IMHO), but never put the buttons in it.  So when you call `colorButtons[0].whatever` you are trying to access `whatever` on the reference at index 0.  But since you didn't put anything in the array, that reference is `null`.

Do something more like

```
JButton[] colorButtons = new JButton[9]; // initialize array
for (int i = 0; i < colorButtons.length; i++) {
   JButton button = ... // initialize button each time thru

   // do any common setup on the buttons

   colorButtons[i] = button; // put the button in the array.
}
```

Comment: Also the JFrame f1 has not been initialized which will cause problems later on.

Comment: I added the comment because he just asked about it in another question which was closed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980984/java-nullpointerexpection-error).

Answer (score 3):

You allocate a new JButton array, but you don't allocate the elements therein:

```
colorbuttons = new JButton[9];
```

There should be a corresponding:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    colorbuttons[i]= new JButton(...);
}
```

Otherwise, you're allocating space for the array of buttons, but never actually initializing each of the JButtons.  Thus, colorbuttons[0] is null, and colorbuttons[0].blah() causes the NPE.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't put anything into the colorbuttons array! Of-course it's null.
Here:

```
for(int i=0; i<colorbuttons.length; i++)
     colorbuttons[i] = new JButton();
```

Answer (score 2):

You JButton array is empty. You just declared it and nothing more.

Populate your array by adding  buttons to it.

Something like this:

```
colorbuttons = new JButton[9];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   //Your logic here 
   colobuttons[i] = new JButton();
}
```